# What path should I store my website files?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a cloud server, and I disabled root login.

I login with user 'demo' (for example sake).

So when I SSH into my server, my home is:

/home/demo

Should I put my website files inside this?

I'm running nginx if that makes a difference.

i.e:

```
/home/demo/domain1.com/
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also create a dedicated folder in /home directory, for example :

```
/home/sites
```

Answer (score 1):

It really doesnt matter that much. You could use a common path like /var/www/ or /srv/www/. You could also put it inside your user home Directory, but if you do not intend to host multiple users with multiple websites on that server, i would prefer a common global path like /var/www/ or /srv/www/.
(see also: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard))